# Antispam MX filter

Tags: spam, smtp

I have an [Exchange Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server)¹ and I'm looking for an antispam and mailpop service to filter messages before they arrives in my server. Can you suggest a service like this?

¹ <sub>Microsoft Exchange Server is a [mail server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_server) and [calendaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendaring_software) server developed by [Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Probably [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) Inbound Mail Gateway service can help. As their [help center article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60730?hl=en) puts it:

> An inbound mail gateway is a server that all your incoming mail passes
>   through. The gateway typically processes the mail in some way, such as
>   archiving it or filtering spam. It then passes the mail to the mail
>   server that delivers the mail to recipients.